# List top 5 scores AND names associated with those scores

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

My Numbers spreadsheet has a column of summed scores (`AA`) from a gymnastics meet, the All-Around scores. Each score in this column is associated with a specific gymnast name in another column (`Name`).

What I'm trying to do is populate a smaller spreadsheet that will parse the top 5 (or more) scores AND names associated with those scores into two columns - one for `names`, the other for `scores`.

This should be something very simple, but I haven't ever played with Excel or Numbers and am really struggling to make sense of all the syntax and formulas.

I've created a link to an image of the columns in question for reference.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5w819hz1iyhpdde/Scores.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Create a pivot table and the set the Top 10 (you can set later to any number)

More info:
http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-filters-top10.html

Answer (score 1):

This can be broken down into three steps.
Let's say you need the 5th largest element.

1. Use Large to get the 5th largest element. `LARGE(b:b, 5)`
2. The above returns the 5th largest value in the b:b range. But you need to know which row number this is in the B column. For that we use `MATCH`. Use, `MATCH(lookup value, range, 0)` where lookup value is the one returned in the first step, range is again B:B and 0 means exact match.
3. We need to find the appropriate name associated with the largest value. We use `INDEX`, which finds the value at a particular index value. Use, `INDEX(name range, row_number)` where name range is say A:A and row_number is the one returned in the previous step.

To sum it up, you need:

`INDEX(A:A, MATCH(LARGE(B:B,5),B:B,0))` to get the 5th largest name. Change 5 to whatever rank you want!

Comment: @matthew-zeller Was this helpful?